# The easist way to modify firestore data without deploy cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to modify docs on firestore without deploy cloud functions?  My project is just in progress, and sometimes, I just want to modify all player's scores or something else, but I need to deploy a test cloud function for doing this. What's the normal way to do this?
I have checked Firesore CLI but it only supports delete docs not update, add, etc.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the Firebase `admin` SDK on your local device. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) are some instructions how to do it. I use it always to sync or update large amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

You could locally emulate the functions. I usually create separate JS files for such recurring actions. For example:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const credential = require("./serviceAccountKey.json")

admin.initializeApp({
  credential,
  databaseURL: "https://<projectID>.firebaseio.com/"
})

const db = admin.firestore()

return db.collection("players").get().then((playersSnapshot) => {
  const docIDs = playersSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.id)
  const updates = docIDs.map(docId => db.collection("players").doc(docId).update({...}))

  return Promise.all(updates).then(() => console.log(`${docIDs.length} docs updated!`))
})
```

Then just run the script by `node filename.js` and the updates should be done! So now you just need to run that one command to perform that action again.

Comment: @Scozirge2 sure, let me know if there are any further queries. If it was helpful you can accept it by clicking the tick icon :D